# how to deactivate past dates in jquery

Tags: javascript

i am using jquery calendar and i want to deactivate all the past dates.
user can only enter the current date or date that is greater than current date.
i am using this code

```
<!-- calendar code starts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calendar2/tcal.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="calendar2/tcal.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $("#dt").datepicker({ minDate: new Date() });
     </script> 
<!-- calendar code ends-->

html code
<div><input type="text" id="dt" name="requireddate" 
class="tcal" value="<?php echo $rec5['requireddate']; ?>" /> </div>
```

but the above code is not working..it shows all past dates

i am using this calendar `http://www.softcomplex.com/products/tigra_calendar/`

Comment: i have just added the link of calendar in my question

Comment: First of all, tcal is not jquery plugin, it is pure javascript. Also there is no mention of such feature of setting minDate in tcal's page. And I didn't find any mention of such in it's source code.

Comment: can't you try jquery ui datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max

Comment: i am very very new in php and javascript. i just download this caledar and added to my page.. is there any way to disable past dates in this calendar

Comment: yes in jquery ui datepicker. check the link i gave. the demo points straight to this feature. You need to write something like `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });`. which means enable days from 20 days before till 1month and 10 days afters today

Answer (score 1):

**update**
*Just noticed that you do not use the jquery UI.. my answer is based on that..*

---

**Answer (*based on jQuery UI datepicker*)**

In your example the previous dates are de-activated..

They are shown, but not selectable..

do you want them to not be visible ?

To do that you can use the `beforeShowDay` event, to apply a class to the old days and hide them with css

**Script**

```
var today = new Date();
$("#dt").datepicker({
    minDate: today,
    beforeShowDay: function(cdate){
        var old = cdate < today;
        return [true, old?'old':''];
    }
});
```

and **CSS**

```
td.old span{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/s2ZmQ/1/

Comment: @sv_in, yes.. just updated answer to reflect this.. i hadn't notice the OP was using a different datepicker..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli.. i want to deactivate or disable all past dates. the code i mentioned is not working.. it shows all past dates

Comment: @maham i am sorry but the plugin you use does not support any kind of customization... you need to use some other plugin.. jQuery UI datepicker seems the perfect fit ..

Comment: could you please send me the download link. i am sorry i am very very new in php and javascript

Comment: @maham, look at http://jqueryui.com/download (select core and datepicker) and you will also need jquery (http://jquery.com/)